# How to change OG "subscribe to group" link text?

Tags: organic-groups

I want to customize the link text, don't want to use string overrides module for this small job.

In my template_preprocess_node() function I tried to change the #title element of the render array. But it doesn't change the link. Any ideas?

```
//change the "subscribe link for tribes
if ($variables['type'] == 'tribe'){
    if (isset($variables['elements']['group_group']['0']['#title'])){
        $variables['elements']['group_group']['0']['#title'] = 'Join this Tribe';
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, when I use print_r I can see that there are 2 #tribe fields in the array. Is there a better way of finding it other than clicking each option in the dpm() output. When I use print_r() I find it but can't make out the path.

Comment: found it, it was $variables['content']['group_group']['0']['#title'] = 'Join this Tribe'; I posted another question about finding elements in the render array: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28109/how-to-find-elements-in-a-render-array

Answer (score 5):

You don't necessarily need to use the string overrides module. You can add string overrides directly in your settings.php.

```php
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  'Subscribe to group' => 'Join this Tribe',
);
```

For more information, see [Change default strings (text) without using full translation system](https://www.drupal.org/node/522036).

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out.

In Drupal 7 after you've added the Group Content Visibility to the Organic Group Field Settings (admin/config/group/fields) for the bundle of the content type you're wanting to change this within then you simply go to Manage Fields for that content type and Edit the Field where you can change the Title as well as the language in the options.

In my case I made the title "Share with" and the allowed values list to:

1|Public - visible to all site users
2|Private - visible to only my followers

Comment: Does that also apply to the "Subscribe to group" link text? Which field do you need to edit there? I can't find any.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change code, the [stringoverrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module does a great job. Install it, enable it, go to configuration -> string overrides and add a new line with 'subscribe to group' and 'Join this Tribe'.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem just now. It looks like the best way to determine which message is being displayed to the user is by the class name applied to the output. I found five distinct messages that can be displayed to the end user in the [`og_ui_field_formatter_view`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21og%21og_ui%21og_ui.module/function/og_ui_field_formatter_view/7) function and decided to replace them all. I also decided to `unset` all the element `title` attributes, instead of updating the duplicate text in each `title` attribute.

```
<?php
function MODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['type'] == 'NODE TYPE') {
    $field_value = &$variables['content']['group_group'][0];
    $is_link = $field_value['#type'] == 'link';
    $class = $is_link ?
      reset($field_value['#options']['attributes']['class']) :
      $field_value['#attributes']['class'];
    switch ($class) {
      case 'group subscribe':
        $field_value['#title'] = t('I am an employee here');
        unset($field_value['#options']['attributes']['title']);
        break;
      case 'group unsubscribe':
        $field_value['#title'] = t('I no longer work for this company');
        unset($field_value['#options']['attributes']['title']);
        break;
      case 'group other':
        $field_value['#value'] = t('You are already subscribed to other groups');
        unset($field_value['#attributes']['title']);
        break;
      case 'group closed':
        $field_value['#value'] = t('This is a closed listing. Only an administrator can add you.');
        unset($field_value['#attributes']['title']);
        break;
      case 'group manager':
        $field_value['#value'] = t('This is my company');
        unset($field_value['#attributes']['title']);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check if current user is subscribed to group and check link text according to that.

```
if (module_exists('og')) {
  if (og_is_member('node', $variables['nid'])) {
    // We do not alter "You are the group manager" text.
    // Assuming that group admin will only have permission to administer group.
    if (!og_user_access('node', $variables['nid'], 'administer group')) {
      $variables['content']['group_group'][0]['#title'] = t('Leave this group');
    }
  }
  else {
    $variables['content']['group_group'][0]['#title'] = t('Join this group');
  }
}
```

Write this code in [template_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node). This code snippet works for Drupal 7.