# How to find elements in a render array

Tags: theming

I just spent a lot of time finding an element in a render array. I usually use `dpm()` to print the array, and then expand the options until I find what I'm looking for.

On larger arrays that's cumbersome. When I use `print_r()`, I can do a text search, but then it's hard to see the structure of the array and find the path to the element.

What other methods can you suggest?

Comment: This Question is worth to add my full reps !!

Comment: There are some modules to pretty up all this *caca*. I am too lazy to go look but dev module integrates with krumo and other dump-enhancers, if I remember correctly. Then there's always a good old debugger, where you can actually inspect and drive down in objects even.

Comment: @stefgosselin OP is already using the Devel module with `dpm()`, I think he's looking for a function to find a sub-element within a render array by a given name/key

Comment: @MotoTribe If I've got that right and you're looking for a function, what sort of input/output would you be hoping to give/get from it? Would it be something like `$elements = find_elements_by_key($render_array, 'element_name');` to return an array of all of the elements in the render array with a matching key?

Comment: correct. In devel the "krumo display = disabled" shows a better formatted array where I can use a text search. Ideally there should be a search function in the krumo output and a "copy" feature where I can copy the full array path ['...']['...'] without having to type it.  Yeah, your function would be awesome too. That's not a Drupal or PHP function, is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is extension module for Devel: [Search Krumo](http://drupal.org/project/search_krumo). It uses Javascript to find text in Krumo/dpm messages and open array in those places.
Looks like this:
[image]

### Update

After [22 Apr 2012](http://drupalcode.org/project/search_krumo.git/commit/51b05ac62203889c45e4a814c7d4badf29636d3d) you should use `sdpm()` function to see search box.

Comment: no way, that's exactly what I was looking for!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: @MotoTribe, so it can be accepted, I think :)

Comment: sorry, missed that one. This is an awesome tool, use it all the time now!!!

Comment: where i put this extension module? either inside devel directory [\www\drupal\sites\all\modules\devel]or inside contributed modules directory[\www\drupal\sites\all\modules]

Comment: Could you please mention that how to use sdpm() function? where to paste? Very Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

One of the big problems with render arrays is that there are often a bunch of read-only copies of the information that you're looking for. If you want to actually *change* the render output, you have to find the right one. I usually use dpm(), and then view page source and search through the output there, flipping back and forth between the two displays until I find what I need.

If you want to dump the contents of a render array for a given path to the terminal (e.g. to pass it through grep), you could do something like this:

```
drush ev '$router_item=menu_get_item("node/7"); require_once(DRUPAL_ROOT .
"/" . $router_item["include_file"]);
$render_array=call_user_func_array($router_item["page_callback"],
$router_item["page_arguments"]); print_r($render_array);'
```

You could also just 'view page source' in your browser and use the clipboard, of course, but the above might be the start of a Drush command to view render arrays.

**Update:** I found a really good article on this subject: The [Scary Render Array](http://cocoate.com/node/8335) -- probably the best treatment of render arrays I have seen so far.  I should have also mentioned the [devel_themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module upfront; it does a good job at "zooming in" on the section of the render array you are interested in.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for linking to The Scary Render Array - great article!